# Creating P4 Credential In Jenkins VIA API

Tags: jenkins, ansible, credentials

I'm creating a playbook to set up a Jenkins master and wanted to use the Jenkins API to create a P4 credential with SSL enabled

I have tried various methods of setting ssl, e.g. "ssl": "true" , "ssl": { "trust": "*** fingerprint ***" } but not having much luck

The below creates the basic credential but does not set the SSL and trust fingerprint

```
- name: Add Perforce Credential
  uri:
    method: POST
    url: 'http://{{ jenkins_hostname }}:{{ jenkins_http_port }}credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials/'
    user: "{{ jenkins_admin_username }}"
    password: "{{ jenkins_admin_password }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 302
    validate_certs: no
    headers:
      Jenkins-Crumb: "{{ crumb.content.split(':')[1] }}"
    body: |
      json={
        "": "0",
        "credentials": {
          "scope": "GLOBAL",
          "id": "{{ credential_p4 }}",
          "username": "{{ credential_p4 }}",
          "password": "{{ credential_p4_password }}",
          "description": "{{ credential_p4 }} Credential",
          "p4port": "{{ credential_p4_port }}",
          "stapler-class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.credentials.P4PasswordImpl"
        }
      }
```

Typically my efforts have resulted in the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to convert to class org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.credentials.TrustImpl
```

Any pointers to where I'm going wrong

Thanks

Comment: First, it it highly suspicious that you have a JSON payload with an empty key; secondly, you have left off the **rest** of the error message, explaining why it was unable to convert something to a `TrustImpl`; we'll need the full error message if you expect to get any help. Also, using string interpolation for building up a JSON payload is risky, since if your password contains any non-JSON-friendly characters it will explode, possibly in exactly the way you are describing here. The correct thing is to make a `dict` and send it through the `to_json` filter

Comment: @Matthew L Daniel - Thanks Matthew for the response I have removed the empty key and ultimately will remove the string interpolation (although as I can create the credential - minus the SSL trust I don't think that's causing a problem).   I have managed to sort this issue by adding a new key

Comment: "ssl": {
            "trust": "{{ credential_p4_trust }}",
            "stapler-class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.p4.credentials.TrustImpl",
          }